# Handling Of Database (sqlite) for Django on Heroku

Tags: python, django, sqlite, heroku, deployment

[Error Log][1]

I had run "heroku run python manage.py migrate" yet the migrate aren't working.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKtZr.png

Comment: Plenty of questions about this already. Don't attempt to use SQLite on Heroku -- won't work. Postgres is a good alternative.

Comment: Why did you tag MySql if your database is SQLite?

Comment: How do I migrate to Postges

Answer (score 0):

sqlite won't work in heroku. you have to use postgres.

login to heroku and add postgres db to you app(blog--curd--django).

add `dj-database-url` to requirements.txt

now update you `setting.py`:

```
...
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config()}
```

then run migrate:

```
$ heroku run -a blog--curd--django python manage.py migrate
```